# Laravel eloquent firstOrNew method doesn't update or insert

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, eloquent

I have a problem with `firstOrNew()` method of the Laravel eloquent class. the problem is that when I give the method some attributes and values and call `save()` on the model, it doesn't get saved (inserted or updated).

**PHP :**

```
<?

$flightModel = Flight::firstOrNew([
    'arrival' => $flightData['arrival'],
    'plane' => $flightData['plane']
]);

$flightModel->departure = $flightData['departure'];

$flightModel->save();//this doesn't save any data
```

But when I try this with a new model it gets saved :

```
<?

$flightModel = new Flight();
$flightModel->arrival = $flightData['arrival'];
$flightModel->plane = $flightData['plane'];
$flightModel->departure = $flightData['departure'];

$flightModel->save();
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Is `arrival` and `plane` set to fillable in your Flight model?

Comment: @aynber I have set `$fillable` to `'*'` and `$guarded` to `[]`

Comment: Can you use a wildcard? I didn't think that was an option. Perhaps try explicitly setting `arrival` and `plane`, because what you have above should work. Also, you should specify _either_ `fillable` or `guarded`, as per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models).

Comment: Looking at the Model.php, only guarded can use a wildcard. You must explicitly set each fillable field.

Comment: @camelCase I have set the fields explicitly on the `$fillable` variable but no luck. nothing changed

Comment: @aynber I have set the fields explicitly on the `$fillable` variable but no luck. nothing changed

Comment: Also I have used on of those 2 properties : `fillable` or `guarded`

Comment: How about trying `firstOrCreate` instead, does it create the new model?