# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause'

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, composite-key, polymorphic-relationship

I keep getting the error

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where
>   clause' "

with the sql output:

```sql
    update `contactables` set `updated_at` = 2019-08-16 20:35:56, `active` = 0 where `` is null and `key_ID` = 235852
```

I was attempting to use the eloquent **firstOrNew/firstOrCreate** method on a polymorphic model. I've tried all sorts of variants of this:

```php
  $record1 = Contactable::firstOrNew(
    [
     'contactable_ID' => $location_ID,
     'user_ID' => $user_ID,
     'contactable_type' => Location::class,
    ]);
  $record = Contactable::find($record1->key_ID);
  $record->fill(
    [
     'active' => $active,
    ]);
  $record->save();
```

```php
    $primaryKey = 'key_ID';
    $guarded = [];
    $fillable = [
        'user_ID',
        'use_loc_contact_info',
        'contactable_ID',
        'contactable_type',
        'active',
        'flag',
        'print_and_save',
        'marketing',
      ];
```

This appears to only happen when trying to update a record where I actually change something. Creating records seems to work fine, updating where I don't change anything seems to work. I'm at a total loss as to what to do next...

I've looked at these (and a dozen+ others that weren't really related):

[Laravel eloquent firstOrNew method doesn't update or insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208033/laravel-eloquent-firstornew-method-doesnt-update-or-insert)

[laravel auth:api returns SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where ``](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298109/laravel-authapi-returns-sqlstate42s22-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column)

Thanks for any help, or new questions!

Comment: ....`active` = 0 where `` ....Aren't you supposed to mention the column name after where?

Comment: you have empty ''

Comment: give column name in   ...... `columnName` is null and `key_ID` = 235852

Comment: Is the error coming from `$record1->save();` or are you also saving `$record`?

Comment: @Praveen/@ Payam --> Sorry, to clarify, I know that the problem is there should be a column name inside the quotes, what I don't understand is why eloquent is putting a where statement in the query when I'm matching the record on the key_ID primary key. After reflecting on this over the weekend, maybe I need to open a bug with laravel eloquent.

@Jonas --> I'll fix the code in my question. I had tried a hundred permutations and included the wrong one in my question. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: Please post the whole `Contactable` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a fair amount of looking around, I finally found a solution for this [based on this issue I stumbled across](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5517#issuecomment-98530235). I forgot that this table has a composite key, which was the source for this problem.

I included this in my custom pivot model to override the laravel default for **"setKeysForSaveQuery"**:

```
class Contactable extends MorphPivot {
    ...
    protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query) {
        $query
            //Put appropriate values for keys here:
            ->where('contactable_type', '=', $this->contactable_type)
            ->where('contactable_ID', '=', $this->contactable_ID)
            ->where('user_ID', '=', $this->user_ID);

        return $query;
    }
    ...
}
```

it worked like a charm, and fixed the problem that was resulting in eloquent creating the `...where '' is null and 'key_ID' = 235852` query

I also referenced the following that informed my solution but mostly didn't solve my overly complex composite-key-on-custom-polymorphic-relationship problem. I hope this path helps someone else.

[Laravel eloquent firstOrNew method doesn't update or insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208033/laravel-eloquent-firstornew-method-doesnt-update-or-insert)

[Creating and Update Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839941/creating-and-update-laravel-eloquent)

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2393

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355

[Laravel Model with Two Primary Keys update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332005/laravel-model-with-two-primary-keys-update)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#creating-indexes

[How I can put composite keys in models in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415213/how-i-can-put-composite-keys-in-models-in-laravel-5)

https://blog.maqe.com/solved-eloquent-doesnt-support-composite-primary-keys-62b740120f

https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/alrgwk/composite_key_in_table_only/

Answer (score 1):

I used this fix in Laravel 5.4, very similar to the previous answer by Kevin Foster and taken from https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5517

Insert this in your Laravel Model for the table in question - insert the column names for the composite key in place of column1 and column2

Solved my problem - thanks to previous contributor

```
/**
 * Set the keys for a save update query.
 * This is a fix for tables with composite keys
 * TODO: Investigate this later on
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
{
    $query
        //Put appropriate values for your keys here:
        ->where('column1', '=', $this->column1)
        ->where('column2', '=', $this->column2);

    return $query;
}
```

You will also need to include:

```
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
```

Comment: If parts of this question/ answer helped you, please consider voting for the parts that helped you. Thanks for contributing!